# How to print the in same line?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I having problem in printing the hash element in same line.

```
t#!/usr/bin/perl
#use Data::Dumper;
my $file3 = 'file1.csv';
my $file2 = 'file2.csv';
my $file1 = 'file3.csv';

open (my $fh_dest, ">", "outputfile.csv") or die "Can't open > outputfile.csv: $!";

my %HoA1;
my %HoA2;
my %HoA3;
open (MODIFIED_FILE2, $file1) or  die ("Could not open $file1!");
while(<MODIFIED_FILE2>){
   chomp;
   my ($k, $v1,$v2,$v3,$v4) = split /,/,$_,5;
   push @{$HoA1{'MODIFIED_FILE2'}{$k}},$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4;
}
close(MODIFIED_FILE2);

open (MODIFIED_FILE1, $file2) or  die ("Could not open $file2!");
while(<MODIFIED_FILE1>){
   chomp;
   my ($k, $v1,$v2,$v3) = split /,/,$_,4;
   push @{$HoA2{'MODIFIED_FILE1'}{$k}},$v1,$v2,$v3;
}
close(MODIFIED_FILE1);

open (BASE_FILE, $file3) or die ("Could not open $file3!");
while(<BASE_FILE>){
   chomp;
   my ($k, $v1,$v2,$v3) = split /,/,$_,4;
   push @{$HoA3{'BASE_FILE'}{$k}},$v1,$v2,$v3;
}
close(BASE_FILE);

#print $fh_dest Dumper \%HoA;
foreach my $MODIFIED_FILE2 (keys %{ $HoA1{'MODIFIED_FILE2'} }) {
   if (exists $HoA3{'BASE_FILE'}{$MODIFIED_FILE2}) {
    print $fh_dest "-" x 60, "\n";
    print $fh_dest "$MODIFIED_FILE2\nMODIFIED_FILE2   MODIFIED_FILE1     BASE_FILE\n";
        print $fh_dest "-" x 60, "\n";

        foreach my $class_BASE_FILE ( @{$HoA3{'BASE_FILE'}{$MODIFIED_FILE2}} ) { 
    printf $fh_dest "%-20s%-20s%s\n",$class_MODIFIED_FILE2,$class_MODIFIED_FILE1,$class_BASE_FILE;
    }
    foreach my $class_MODIFIED_FILE1 ( @{$HoA2{'MODIFIED_FILE1'}{$MODIFIED_FILE2}} ) {
    printf $fh_dest "%-20s%s\n",$class_MODIFIED_FILE2,$class_MODIFIED_FILE1;
    }
    foreach my $class_MODIFIED_FILE2 ( @{$HoA1{'MODIFIED_FILE2'}{$MODIFIED_FILE2}} ) {
    printf $fh_dest "%s\n",$class_MODIFIED_FILE2;
    }
      print $fh_dest "\n";
}
 

   elsif (exists $HoA2{'MODIFIED_FILE1'}{$MODIFIED_FILE2}) {
    print $fh_dest "-" x 60, "\n";
    
    print $fh_dest "$MODIFIED_FILE2\nMODIFIED_FILE2   MODIFIED_FILE1     BASE_FILE\n";
    print $fh_dest "-" x 60, "\n";
    
    foreach my $class_MODIFIED_FILE1 ( @{$HoA2{'MODIFIED_FILE1'}{$MODIFIED_FILE2}} ) {
    printf $fh_dest "%-20s%s\n",$class_MODIFIED_FILE2,$class_MODIFIED_FILE1;
    }  
    foreach my $class_MODIFIED_FILE2 ( @{$HoA1{'MODIFIED_FILE2'}{$MODIFIED_FILE2}} ) {
    printf $fh_dest "%s\n",$class_MODIFIED_FILE2;
    }
      print $fh_dest "\n";
  }


   else {
    print $fh_dest "-" x 60, "\n"; 
    print $fh_dest "$MODIFIED_FILE2\nMODIFIED_FILE2   MODIFIED_FILE1     BASE_FILE\n";
    print $fh_dest "-" x 60, "\n";

    foreach my $class_MODIFIED_FILE2 ( @{$HoA1{'MODIFIED_FILE2'}{$MODIFIED_FILE2}} ) {
    printf $fh_dest "%s\n",$class_MODIFIED_FILE2;
    }  
      print $fh_dest "\n";
  }
}

close ($fh_dest);
```

The output I get :

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Dora
MODIFIED_FILE2    MODIFIED_FILE1     BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
                    34
                    Malaysian
                    Malay 
34
Malaysian
Arab
B- 

------------------------------------------------------------
Boszor
MODIFIED_FILE2    MODIFIED_FILE1     BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
                                        91
                                        Mexico
                                        Chinese
                    91
                    Mexico
                    Chinese
91
Mexico
Chinese
AB+

------------------------------------------------------------
Szundi
MODIFIED_FILE2    MODIFIED_FILE1     BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
                                        23
                                        German
                                        Indian
                    23
                    German
                    Indian
23
German
Indian
AB-
```

the expected output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Dora
MODIFIED_FILE2    MODIFIED_FILE1     BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
34                        34
Malaysian               Malaysian
Malay                    Arab
B- 

------------------------------------------------------------
Boszor
MODIFIED_FILE2    MODIFIED_FILE1     BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
91                         91                   91
Mexico                    Mexico              Mexico
Chinese                   Chinese             Chinese
AB+
 
------------------------------------------------------------
Szundi
MODIFIED_FILE2    MODIFIED_FILE1     BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
23                         23                   23
German                    German              German
Indian                    Indian              Indian
AB-
```

Comment: It's best to provide a minimum working example. We don't know what's in the input CSV files. Can you hardcode the variable values for this question?

Comment: Also, you should add `use strict;` at the top of all Perl code (also add `use warnings;` for Perl versions before 5.35). It might give you some insight into what's going on.

Comment: sample data would be helpful - especially data that correlates to the output shown.

Comment: @suba suba – 
Why did you swap `Arab` and `Malay` in the first and second columns of `Dora` between _output_ and _expected output_?

Answer (score 2):

There is a somewhat archiac feature of perl that does exactly what you were looking for --- the "format".

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $name='';
my $v=undef;
format STDOUT =
-----------------------------------------------------------
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$name
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
#==================#===================#===================#
@|||||||||||||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||@||||||||||||||||||
$v->[0][0]//'',     $v->[1][0]//'',     $v->[2][0]//'',
@|||||||||||||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||@||||||||||||||||||
$v->[0][1]//'',     $v->[1][1]//'',     $v->[2][1]//'',
@|||||||||||||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||@||||||||||||||||||
$v->[0][2]//'',     $v->[1][2]//'',     $v->[2][3]//'',
@|||||||||||||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||@||||||||||||||||||
$v->[0][3]//'',     $v->[1][3]//'',     $v->[2][3]//''

.

{
    # Test format
    # clear the columns at the beginning of the loop
    $v=undef;

    # set values for the various lines
    $name='decline the in german';

    # set values to used in third column
    $v->[2]=[qw(das des dem das)];

    # set values to used in second column
    $v->[1]=[qw(die der der die)];

    # set values to used in first column
    $v->[0]=[qw(der des dem den)];

    {
        # Safely output the format STDOUT
        my $old_handle=select STDOUT;

        # This goes to $new_handle:
        write;

        # restore the perevious handle
        select $old_handle;
        };
    };
```

For our test this yields

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
decline the in germ
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
        der                 die                 das
        des                 der                 des
        dem                 der                 das
        den                 die                 das
```

Using this we can simplify your code to

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $name='';
my $v=undef;
format STDOUT =
-----------------------------------------------------------
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$name
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
#==================#===================#===================#
@|||||||||||||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||@||||||||||||||||||
$v->[0][0]//'',     $v->[1][0]//'',     $v->[2][0]//'',
@|||||||||||||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||@||||||||||||||||||
$v->[0][1]//'',     $v->[1][1]//'',     $v->[2][1]//'',
@|||||||||||||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||@||||||||||||||||||
$v->[0][2]//'',     $v->[1][2]//'',     $v->[2][3]//'',
@|||||||||||||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||@||||||||||||||||||
$v->[0][3]//'',     $v->[1][3]//'',     $v->[2][3]//''

.

if (0) { # This is just for checking out our format
    # Test format
    # clear the columns at the beginning of the loop
    $v=undef;

    # set values for the various lines
    $name='decline the in german';

    # set values to used in third column
    $v->[2]=[qw(das des dem das)];

    # set values to used in second column
    $v->[1]=[qw(die der der die)];

    # set values to used in first column
    $v->[0]=[qw(der des dem den)];

    {
        # Safely output the format STDOUT
        my $old_handle=select STDOUT;

        # This goes to $new_handle:
        write;

        # restore the perevious handle
        select $old_handle;
        };
    };

my %HoHoA;

    sub read_csv {
        my ($filename,$tag,$values)=@_;
        open(my $FILE,'<',$filename)
            or die "Could not open '$filename'! $!";
        my %HoA;
        while (<$FILE>) {
            chomp;
            my ($k,@value)=split /,/,$_,$values;
            $HoHoA{$k}{$tag}=\@value;
            }
        close($FILE);
        } # sub read_csv

# Read in the data
read_csv('file3.csv','MODIFIED_FILE2',5);
read_csv('file2.csv','MODIFIED_FILE1',4);
read_csv('file1.csv','BASE_FILE',4);

#;warn Data::Dumper->new([\%HoHoA],[qw(*HoHoA)])->Deepcopy(1)->Indent(1)->Maxdepth(3)->Sortkeys(1)->Dump(),q{ };

for my $key (sort keys %HoHoA) {
    # clear/set the values used in the format
    $name=$key;
    $v=undef;

    # Put the stuff in columns --- just for fun they're out of order
    $v->[2]=$HoHoA{$key}{'BASE_FILE'}                       # third column
        if (exists $HoHoA{$key}{'BASE_FILE'});
    $v->[1]=$HoHoA{$key}{'MODIFIED_FILE1'}                  # second column
        if (exists $HoHoA{$key}{'MODIFIED_FILE1'});
    $v->[0]=$HoHoA{$key}{'MODIFIED_FILE2'};                 # first column

    {
        # Safely output the format STDOUT
        my $old_handle=select STDOUT;

        # This goes to $new_handle:
        write;

        # restore the perevious handle
        select $old_handle;
        };
    };

__DATA__
```

which gives

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Boszor
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
         91                  91                 91
       Mexico              Mexico             Mexico
      Chinese             Chinese
        AB+

-----------------------------------------------------------
Dora
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
         34                  34
     Malaysian           Malaysian
       Malay                Arab
         B-
```

In response to your post that was closed - modifying the subroutine "read_csv" will do what you desire. The updated version of read_csv look like:

```
sub read_csv {
    my ($filename,$tag,$values)=@_;
    my $FILE;
    my $raw=do{
        open $FILE,'<',$filename
            or die "Could not open '$filename'! $!";
        # discard the first three lines (header etc)
        <$FILE>,<$FILE>,<$FILE>;
        # slurp the rest
        local $/=undef;
        <$FILE>;
        };
    #;warn Data::Dumper->new([\$raw],[qw(*raw)])->Deepcopy(1)->Indent(1)->Maxdepth(3)->Sortkeys(1)->Dump(),q{ };
    # remove all of those -----'s
    $raw =~ s{^[-]+$(\r?\n)?}{}gms;
    #warn Data::Dumper->new([\$raw],[qw(*raw)])->Deepcopy(1)->Indent(1)->Maxdepth(3)->Sortkeys(1)->Dump(),q{ };
    # Use $raw as the buffer to read from
    open $FILE,'<',\$raw;
    while (<$FILE>) {
        chomp;
        my ($k,@value)=split /,/,$_,$values;
        $HoHoA{$k}{$tag}=\@value;
        }
    close($FILE);
    } # sub read_csv
```

This yields

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Boszor
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
         91                  91                 91
       Mexico              Mexico             Mexico
      Chinese             Chinese
        AB+

-----------------------------------------------------------
Dora
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
         34                  34
     Malaysian           Malaysian
        Arab               Malay
         B-

-----------------------------------------------------------
Queeny
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
         47
       Rusia
      Russian
        O+`

-----------------------------------------------------------
Sarah
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
         21                  21
     Malaysian           Indonesia
       Bugis               Bugis`
        AB+

-----------------------------------------------------------
Szundi
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
         23                  23                 23
       German              German             German
       Indian              Indian
        AB-

-----------------------------------------------------------
Tharani
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
         30
     Australia
       Malay
         O-

-----------------------------------------------------------
Tudor
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
         10                  10                 10
       Spain               Spain              Vietnam
      Chinese             Chinese
         A+
```

In response to the OP's comment

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $output='outputfile.csv';

# declaring variables used in MyFORMAT
my $name='';
my $v=undef;
# more on format https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform
format MyFORMAT =
-----------------------------------------------------------
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$name
MODIFIED_FILE2      MODIFIED_FILE1      BASE_FILE
------------------------------------------------------------
#==================#===================#===================#
@|||||||||||||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||@||||||||||||||||||
$v->[0][0]//'',     $v->[1][0]//'',     $v->[2][0]//'',
@|||||||||||||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||@||||||||||||||||||
$v->[0][1]//'',     $v->[1][1]//'',     $v->[2][1]//'',
@|||||||||||||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||@||||||||||||||||||
$v->[0][2]//'',     $v->[1][2]//'',     $v->[2][3]//'',
@|||||||||||||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||@||||||||||||||||||
$v->[0][3]//'',     $v->[1][3]//'',     $v->[2][3]//''

.
                                       # note the "." which ends the format
                                       # NB nothing else can be on that line not even a comment

my %HoHoA;

sub read_csv {
    my ($filename,$tag,$values)=@_;
    my $FILE;
    my $raw=do{
        open $FILE,'<',$filename
            or die "Could not open '$filename'! $!";
        # discard the first three lines (header etc)
        <$FILE>,<$FILE>,<$FILE>;
        # slurp the rest
        local $/=undef;
        <$FILE>;
        };
    #;warn Data::Dumper->new([\$raw],[qw(*raw)])->Deepcopy(1)->Indent(1)->Maxdepth(3)->Sortkeys(1)->Dump(),q{ };
    # remove all of those -----'s
    $raw =~ s{^[-]+$(\r?\n)?}{}gms;
    #warn Data::Dumper->new([\$raw],[qw(*raw)])->Deepcopy(1)->Indent(1)->Maxdepth(3)->Sortkeys(1)->Dump(),q{ };
    # Use $raw as the buffer to read from
    open $FILE,'<',\$raw;
    while (<$FILE>) {
        chomp;
        my ($k,@value)=split /,/,$_,$values;
        $HoHoA{$k}{$tag}=\@value;
        }
    close($FILE);
    } # sub read_csv

# Read in the data building a Hash of Hashes of Arrays
# with the key of the outer hash being the ID
# and the key of the inner hash being the tag (ie: 'BASE_FILE' etc)
read_csv('file3.csv','MODIFIED_FILE2',5);
read_csv('file2.csv','MODIFIED_FILE1',4);
read_csv('file1.csv','BASE_FILE',4);

#;warn Data::Dumper->new([\%HoHoA],[qw(*HoHoA)])->Deepcopy(1)->Indent(1)->Maxdepth(3)->Sortkeys(1)->Dump(),q{ };

# Open a handle to $output
open my $MyHANDLE,'>',$output
    or die "Could not open '$output'! $!";

# Associate the handle with its format
# More on "->format name" https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#HANDLE-%3Eformat_name(EXPR)
# note - because the format is invariant within the loop we can set it here
$MyHANDLE->format_name('MyFORMAT');

for my $key (sort keys %HoHoA) {
    # clear/set the values used in the format
    $name=$key;
    $v=undef;

    # Put the stuff in columns --- just for fun they're out of order
    $v->[2]=$HoHoA{$key}{'BASE_FILE'}                       # third column
        if (exists $HoHoA{$key}{'BASE_FILE'});
    $v->[1]=$HoHoA{$key}{'MODIFIED_FILE1'}                  # second column
        if (exists $HoHoA{$key}{'MODIFIED_FILE1'});
    $v->[0]=$HoHoA{$key}{'MODIFIED_FILE2'};                 # first column

    # Associate the handle with its format
    # More on "->format name" https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#HANDLE-%3Eformat_name(EXPR)
    # note - because the format is invariant within the loop it has been move outside the loop
    #$MyHANDLE->format_name('MyFORMAT');

    # More on write https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/write
    write $MyHANDLE;
    };

# Close the handle
close $MyHANDLE
    or die "Could not open '$output'! $!";
__DATA__
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can i how i write the output into different file?, means i want my output to be print into different file called "outputfile.csv".

Comment: @suba suba   the code has been updated to write the output to 'outputfile.csv' but surely you should NOT be writing to an extension of '.csv'.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at your data in terms of records, which you want formatted as columns, but your output medium is row (line) based. You have to transform your columnar data into an output suitable for your medium.

### Use `strict` and `warnings`

All Perl 5 code should enable the `strict` pragma, and ideally use `warnings` pragma especially if you are asking for help. The `strict` pragma would have given you some hints about what went wrong. Enabling `strict` on your code yields several compilation errors.

```
$ perl -c -Mstrict -Mwarnings -wl foo.pl
Global symbol "$class_MODIFIED_FILE2" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $class_MODIFIED_FILE2"?) at foo.pl line 44.
Global symbol "$class_MODIFIED_FILE1" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $class_MODIFIED_FILE1"?) at foo.pl line 44.
Global symbol "$class_MODIFIED_FILE2" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $class_MODIFIED_FILE2"?) at foo.pl line 47.
Global symbol "$class_MODIFIED_FILE2" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $class_MODIFIED_FILE2"?) at foo.pl line 63.
foo.pl had compilation errors.
```

The reason you see this is because you are trying to use variables before you declare them. Since Perl is procedural, it goes line-by-line; it can't print what hasn't been declared yet.

### Use a CPAN module

The simplest answer for this is to use one of several existing CPAN modules. [Data::Format::Pretty::Console](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Format::Pretty::Console) can output your records in columnar format. Other popular CPAN options include [Text::Table](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table), [Text::ASCIITable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ASCIITable).

### Think about your output

This question is not fundamentally a Perl question, but a data/formatting question. Since your target output medium (an ASCII terminal) is based on rows, you have to print one row at a time.

If you want to do this without a module, you have to think in terms of printing one *line* at a time.

Here is a working program that I think accomplishes what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %HoA = (
    MODIFIED_FILE2 => {
        Dora   => [qw(34 Malaysian Malay B-)],
        Boszor => [qw(91 Mexico Chinese AB+)],
    },
    MODIFIED_FILE1 => {
        Dora   => [qw(34 Malaysian Arab)],
        Boszor => [qw(91 Mexico Chinese)],
    },
    BASE_FILE => {
        Boszor => [qw(91 Mexico Chinese)],
    },
);

my @columns = qw(MODIFIED_FILE2 MODIFIED_FILE1 BASE_FILE);

# NOTE use sort to guarantee consistent output
for my $name (sort keys %{ $HoA{MODIFIED_FILE2} }) {
    print "-" x 60, "\n";
    print "$name\n";
    printf "%-20s" x @columns, @columns;
    print "\n";
    print "-" x 60, "\n";

    for my $idx (0..3) { # age, country, ethincity, blood type
        for my $column (@columns) {
            printf "%-20s", $HoA{$column}{$name}[$idx] // q{};
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Notice the `for` (or `foreach`) loops - you have to think about them from the inside out. You want to print each column on the same *line*, which is why column is the inner-most loop and there is no newline printed in that loop.

The next loop out is the index, because you want to print groups of columns (the inner-most loop) per index, along with a newline at the end of each.

Finally, the `$name` is the outermost loop, because you want to print each group of data per name.

This code only checks the names in `$HoA{MODIFIED_FILE2}`, which is what your code was doing. If you actually meant to check all of them, you would probably want to use a `map` with a `List::Util::uniq`.

Comment: thank you for the explanations. but how to include the 3 different file cause i have just send a sample of output but there are many actually so i wanna do by this way but the printing part im not sure of it


my $file3 = 'file1.csv';
my $file2 = 'file2.csv';
my $file1 = 'file3.csv';


my %HoA1;
my %HoA2;
my %HoA3;
3 different hash

Comment: It would be fine to use 3 different hashes instead. But it doesn't make much sense to have hashes with just a single top-level key. Instead, name your variables appropriately - e.g., `%modified_file2`, `%modified_file1`, `%base_file`. If you use 3 separate hashes, then instead of the inner `for` loop, you would do one or more `printf` statements including the 3 different hashes. For example, `printf "%-20s%-20s%-20s\n", $modified_file2{$name}[$idx], $modified_file1{$name}[$idx], $base_file{$name}[$idx];`

Comment: but will that compare the 3 files? i also want to compare the 3 files either they are equal or same?

Comment: @subasuba that detail was not in your original question. This code does no comparisons, but it will print the details of the file in a way that you can compare manually. Whether you use one hash or three, it will be the same result.

Asking to "compare" the files is too general - if you want to see how they differ, there are existing tools like `diff`, `diff3`, or `vimdiff`. Otherwise, you'll need to be more specific on what details you want to compare and how you want to display the results of the comparison.

Comment: 1. Example base file :
 = Name : Szundi, Age: 23, Country: German, Ethnic: Indian
2. Example modified file1 :
= Name : Szundi, Age: 23, Country: German, Ethnic: Indian
3. Example modified file2 :
= Name : Szundi, Age: 23, Country: German, Ethnic: Indian, Bloodtype: AB+

If you see the base file and modified file 1 have same results but however the modified file 2 results show an additional column of infor, so i want to compare this 3 file information and print all the details to show changes
BASE FILE - its output    MODIFIED FILE 1 - its output  MODIFIED FILE 2 - its output

Comment: i want to check whether the name(key) its exist or not

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your end goal is. Your original question was regarding the output formatting. Do you want to perform the comparisons *in code* and report which keys are added, missing, or changed on each file? If so, how do you want to display this results to the user?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want the result to be print in one file (CSV) in a table form.

Comment: 1. Example base file : =Name : Szundi, Age: 23, Country: German, Ethnic: Indian  2. Example modified file1 : = Name : Szundi, Age: 23, Country: Spain, Ethnic: Indian 3. Example modified file2 : = Name : Szundi, Age: 23, Country: Spain, Ethnic: Indian, Bloodtype: AB+. Based on this i want the modified file 2 result which is the latest changed of country and added new coloumn happen however in side it should indicated that from base file the country change (German->Spain).

Comment: If there is no changes happen in all the file it should take the result from base file (which mean the file is same as original file)

Comment: 1. Example base file : =Name : Szundi, Age: 23, Country: German, Ethnic: Indian 2. Example modified file1 : = Name : Szundi, Age: 23, Country: Spain, Ethnic: Indian 3. Example modified file2 : = Name : Szundi, Age: 23, Country: German, Ethnic: Indian, Bloodtype: AB+. Based on this  result which is the latest changed of country (modified file 1) and added new coloumn (modified file 2 ) happen however in side it should indicated that from base file the country change (German->Spain) by modified file 1 and added new column by modified file 2

Comment: The result should merging all the 3 file and display in one output with the comparisons in code and report which keys are added, missing, or changed

Comment: Output file:
`Name | Age | Country |  Ethnic |Bloodtype | 
Szundi| 23 | Spain | Indian | AB+ | -> Country : German (Base File) changes to Spain`

Comment: "I want the result to be print in one file (CSV) in a table form" - do you want CSV or a formatted table output? Our answers have expected the latter, but after reading your comments, I don't think that's the case. With CSV, something like:
`Name,Age,Country,Ethnic,Bloodtype,Changes`; and a record might look like `Szundi,23,Spain,Indian,AB+,Country: German changes to Spain` - does that sound right? No need to deal with formatting. Even so, you are comparing 3 files, right? Which file do you want to print in the CSV record, and how do you want to display changes against the other file?